# jQuery Reverse Drop Toggle & CSS Fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

### [≫ Live Demo On JSFiddle ≪](https://jsfiddle.net/yd7jcrhh/)

### Occurring Problems / Questions

**1). Toggling Show/Hide**

Upon clicking on the same drop toggle, or another, I need to reverse the process of any already clicked drop toggles and then show the clicked drop toggle. The current version simply uses the following jQuery code:

```
$(".HonorBarsList a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().css({ marginBottom : "296px" });
    $(this).parent().css({ borderBottom : "none" });
    $(this).parent().find("ul").show();
});
```

I understand that I could loop through the entire scope, applying the initial CSS to all, however this seems like a rather lengthy way to do this.

**Q).** What is my *best* solution to use here?

**2). Last List Set > `UL` > Top Left Border**

This list is generated via a PHP PDO query, therefore the amount of list items will be unknown. On my provided demo, the last set has only three `LI`'s meaning at the top left corner, there appears to be missing border.

**Q).** Should I fake this by having the link drop toggle's bottom border white and the `UL` simply have all borders, or is there another trick I can use, remembering that the last set could have 1-4 `LI`'s within.

Comment: Your JSFiddle code seems to be different than what you posted above. Could you update any changes?

Comment: @KyleS simply a different class is being called, the above is my local class I'm using whereas on the JSFiddle a different class is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to reset the CSS to all the relevant elements. It might be better to do it with an active class though to make the jQuery code a bit cleaner.

Below is an example of just setting the CSS back to it's defaults before applying the relevent CSS to the clicked element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 "use strict";
 
  $(".myList a").click(function(){
    // store relevent elements
    var parentUl = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass("active-li")) {
      // if clicked element is already active then toggle class
      parentUl.toggleClass("active-ul");
      $this.toggleClass("active-li");
    } else {
      // otherwise remove active class from active elements
      $(".active-ul").removeClass("active-ul");
      $(".active-li").removeClass("active-li");
      // then toggle the active class on the clicked parent element
      parentUl.toggleClass("active-ul");
      $this.toggleClass("active-li");
    }
  });
 
});
```

```css
.myList {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 600px;
 height: auto;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border-top:1px solid black;
}
.myList > li,
.myList > li > ul {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 height: 50px;
 width: 600px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.myList > li > ul > li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 height: 51px;
 width: 150px;
 border-left: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.myList > li > ul > li:last-of-type { border-right: 1px solid black; }

.myList > li > ul > li a {
 display: block;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
.myList > li > ul > li > a > div {
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
.myList > li > ul > li > ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 height: 150px;
 width: 600px;
 margin-top: -1px;
 margin-left: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
 border-left: 1px solid black;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index:1;
}
.myList > li > ul > li:nth-of-type(2) > ul { margin-left: -151px; }
.myList > li > ul > li:nth-of-type(3) > ul { margin-left: -301px; }
.myList > li > ul > li:nth-of-type(4) > ul { margin-left: -451px; }
.myList .active-ul {
  margin-bottom:150px;
}
.myList .active-li {
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
}
.myList .active-li + ul {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myList">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">
          Link Area
        </a>
        <ul>
          <p>Additional Informatioin Area...</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I haven't answered your question about the white space on the last dropdown, but I think that will involve taking a slightly different approach to the styling.

Comment: I noticed that, however this is not of importance for being awarded the answer. I'll figure it out one way or another, I don't think simply adding a white border to the bottom of the toggle will work as then there'll be a 1px white gap if you click on the first list item on the last set to the top left

Comment: I've just realised, your version doesn't toggle back if you click on the toggle again to hide...

Comment: @TimMarshall I have corrected my answer. It now toggles when you click an item again. I have also sorted the issue with the gap on the last item. I have added border top to the `ul` and changed the border border to apply to the `a` tag. I have then used `z-index` to overlay the `a` tag over the `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to use the `.toggle` from jQuery

you can handle initial state and new state onclick event

```
$(".myList a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().css({borderBottomLeftRadius: "150px"});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().css({borderBottomLeftRadius: "0px"});
    });
)};
```